# Blink browser taskbar icon for notification when new message arrive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  making a chat application in Spring. When I send new message to the receiving browser I want to blink the browser task bar icon for notification. How can this be done?

My code for blinking the task bar is as follows (it's not working).

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
setInterval(function () {
    if (x == 0) {
        if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 6000) {
            $('#new_msg').html("Home - Messanger");
            $("ul[id*=myid] li").click(function () {
                clearInterval(1000);
                $('#new_msg').html("Home - Messanger");
            });
            return;
        } else {

        }
        x = 1;
    } else {
        if (x = 1) {
            window.getAttention();
            $('#new_msg').html(send_user + " meassge sent  u..!!");

            x = 0;
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Please help me. Any help I can get will be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work in IE:

pre Win 8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491735(v=vs.85).aspx

Win 8 onwards: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh880842(v=vs.85).aspx